# Java - properties file on dist folder

Tags: java, properties, properties-file

This is my src package:

/src/PropertyAccess.java

/src/config.properties

The config.properties is added to the classpath and is in the Project.jar.

But I want it to be in my dist folder so, whenever my java application needs to be distributed, the user can configure its own properties.

I need to have this structure in my dist folder:
/dist/Project.jar
/dist/config/config.properties.

And my jar needs to load the properties from the dist/config.properties file.

How can this be done?

Comment: It depends on what you use to build your jar

Answer (score 0):

Edit the "-post-compile" target inside the `build.xml` as follows:

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <copy file="textfile.txt" todir="${dist.dir}"/>        
</target>
```

You can place any .properties etc file instead of .txt